# Change Schema of Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using Entity Framework 5 on ASP MVC 4 web site I'm developing.
Because I am using shared hosting which charge for the number of databases I use I would like to run a test site near my production site.

I have two problems:

1) I use Code First and Database Migration. The migration classes seem to embed the schema *dbo* inside the name of the tables.

How can I change the schema according to the test/production flag

2) How can I change the schema from which EF select data?

Thank you,
Ido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both migration and EF take schema from mapping so if you want to change the schema you must update your mapping to use:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>().ToTable("MyTable", "MySchema");
```

and control the value of `MySchema` from configuration but this is really bad idea. One day you forget to change the value and break your production. Use local database for development and test.

Comment: This only answer the second question, thank you. The first question is about the migration scripts which has dbo.TABLE embedded in them, how can I work around that? About the bad idea: I am testing it locally but I also want to be able to test on production. Thank you

Comment: The migration script will have the schema you use in the mapping. It is fixed so if you want to change it later you must generate a script from migration and replace it = no automation.

Comment: I use Code First approach. I prefer to find a way without using ModelBuilder directly, if possible.

Comment: I agree. I manage to go so far without directly using it and relay on the conventions only.

Comment: If you want to relay on conventions only you will not be able to switch schema for querying.

Comment: If I run the line of code you wrote will it clear the model created by convention?

Comment: It will override the definition created by convention.

Answer (score 1):

As already said: use identical databases (structurally) for development, test and production.

The goal of schemas is to group database objects, like we do with namespaces in e.g. C#, or to simplify permissions for groups of database objects. Not to identify database stages. By using them for the latter you also make it much harder, if not impossible, to use schema appropriately. See for instance [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283095%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) MSDN white paper.

It is much easier to use some database name conventions to indicate their purpose.

Comment: You may be right but I am using a shared hosting where I pay for each database I use. I want to be able to run both production and test applications and databases on the same server. I know its not ideal but it is possible.